# Write Slick query in a better way

Tags: scala, slick

I have table1 which looks like

```
Table1(id: Long, name: String, parentId: Long) // self referenceing
Table2(table1Id : Long, someOtherId: Long) // FK with Table1 on table1Id
```

I need to write the following SQL query in slick

```
select t11.* from Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2 on (t1.id = t2.table1Id)
inner join Table1 t11 on (t11.parentId = t1.id)
where t2.someOtherId == 10
```

For this I have written the following code

```
val query1 = Table2.query.filter(_.someOtherId === 10)
val query2 = Table1.query innerJoin query1 on (_.id === _.table1Id)
val query3 = Table1.query innerJoin query2 on (_.parentId === _._1.id)
query3.list.map(_._1)
```

basically Table2 is a lookup table, but it contains the mapping only for the parent record.

We need to find all the parents records for a query on table2 and then expand the parent records into child records from Table1.

My question is that is there a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 2):

I am on my iPad at the moment, hence the brevity.

I'd use the monadic query for this. Check Slick documentation, look for queries, then pick the first inner or outer join example. It oooks similar to what you seem to be looking for here